# Getting data from JSON url using angularJS

Tags: javascript, json, google-api, angularjs

I am really new to using AngularJS and Javascript. I need to get the **totalResults** data from a JSON source that looks like this:

```
{
 "queries": {
  "request": [
   {
    "totalResults": "51"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Once I get the data, I need it to show up in a list using AngularJS. I have tried really hard using .ajax and .getJSON, but I am unable to get either of them to work, given my complete lack of knowledge on using JavaScript. I really appreciate your help! My AngularJS looks like this:

```
function MyController($scope){
        $scope.url = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=[MYKEY]&cx=[MYSECRETKEY]&q=flowers&alt=json&fields=queries(request(totalResults))";
        $scope.newMessage = "";
        $scope.messages = ["Steve Jobs - 515,000,000 results"]; 

        $scope.add = function(){
            $scope.messages.push($scope.newMessage);
        };
        }
  }
```

In the HTML part, I have this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="newMessage">
    <input type="submit" ng-click="add()" value="Click to find out!">
```

When the user clicks the button, I want the url to be called and the `$scope.newMessage` should be the value in totalResults. Thanks for your help!

Comment: plnkr.co/edit/nZkYsxLHLvf3SZNiJKic

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `$http` service: [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

So you can:

```
$scope.add = function(){
  $http.get($scope.url).then(function(response) {
            $scope.newMessage = response.data.queries.request.totalResults;
            $scope.messages.push($scope.newMessage);
  });
};
```

Comment: I thought that callback receives response object, not the data directly. So perhaps it should be `srvResponse.data.queries.request.totalResults`? Or am I wrong?

Comment: hey, this still isn't working for some reason. I tried adding an alert before the  `$scope.newMessage = response.data.queries.request.totalResults;` part, but it's not getting called :(

Comment: This is the issue that Google Chrome is showing:

`TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined
    at Object.MyController.$scope.add (file://localhost/Users/Prajoth/Downloads/index%202.html:16:17)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.js:6129:19
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.js:12496:13
    at Object.Scope.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.js:7770:28)`

Comment: `at Object.Scope.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.js:7850:23)
    at <error: TypeError: Accessing selectionDirection on an input element that cannot have a selection.>
 at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.js:1930:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEach (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.js:110:11)
    at <error: TypeError: Accessing selectionDirection on an input element that cannot have a selection.> `

Answer (score 1):

Read a little in $http service provided by AngularJS

here is the hint to the code that you would use

```
$scope.add = function(){
    $http.get(url).then(function(response){
        queries = response.queries;
        $scope.newMessage = queries.request.totalResults;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See http://plnkr.co/edit/nZkYsxLHLvf3SZNiJKic?p=info

Following your link, I just found one error:

```
var x = searchResults.split('.');
```

don't have function split() if i replace:  x  = "abc"

the result : 
Steve Jobs - 515,000,000 results
 - a.b results
dsgdfg - a.b results

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @pduersteler, But its not a link only answer